# Priority to event while broadcasting in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

Since last few times I asked questions multiple people said put all code so here it is:

**Installation**

- Run npm install --save socket.io-client
- Run npm install --save laravel-echo
- For laravel echo server check
  https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server
- Run composer
  require predis/predis

**Setup laravel echo**

*Go to your app/resources/js/bootstrap.js and add following lines:*

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

Also adding csrf token to head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**Setup Redis**

*Go to your app/.env and change following line:*

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
```

**Setting other things**

1. Make an event

   `php artisan make:event Messages`
2. Implement shouldBroadcast

   `class Messages implements ShouldBroadcast`
3. Add channel name to broadcastOn method

   `public function broadcastOn(){
       return new Private('user.' . $this->user_id);
   }`
4. Pass data through constructor as example:

   `public $data;`

   `protected $user_id;`

   `public function __construct($name, $message, $userid)
   {
       $this->user_id = (string) $userid;
       $this->data = array(
           'name'=> $name,
           'message'=> $message
       );
   }`
5. Make routes

*Go to your app/routes/web.php and add following lines:*

```
Route::post('/push-message/', 'MessageController@push');
Route::get('/messages', 'HomeController@index');
```

6. Setup controllers

*Your HomeController need to have:*

```
public function index() {
    return view('messages');
}
```

*Your MessageController need to have:*

```
public function push() {
    $event = new App\Events\Messages(auth()->user()->name, request('message'), request('userid'));
    broadcast($event);
}
```

7. Setup messages view

*Go to your app/resources/views/messages.blade.php and add following lines:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="messages">
    <!-- Messages from database -->
</div>
<form id="chat">
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
<!-- Here we are setting socket io client -->
Echo.private('user.{{auth()->user()->id}}')
    .listen('Messages', (e) => {
        $('#messages').append('<div class="message">'+e.data.name+': '+e.data.message+'</div>');
    });
$('#chat').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#message').val() == "") {return false;}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/push-message'
        data: {
            userid: 1, //here logged as user with id 2
            message: $('#message').val(),
            '_token': {{ csrf_token() }}
        },
        success: function(success) {
            $('#messages').append('<div class="message">{{auth()->user()->name}}: '+$('#message').val()+'</div>');
            $('#message').val('');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now after I added all code I use I need some help:

- If I change .env `QUEUE_DRIVER` (in laravel 5.6 [doesnt exist in 5.7 {in 5.7 there is `QUEUE_CONNECTION`} ] ) to redis from sync

This everything works without Redis server BUT it is a bit slow, like 3-4 seconds before getting message.

I tried also with redis server and redis-cli on windows but on redis-cli nothing appears...

- If I leave as SYNC it gets message in 1 second or instantly, but on web everyone says redis is faster online and slowish on local machine... So I want to use it.
- Also I tried to set priority to Messages event with `broadcast($event->onQueue('high'));` but it does not work ( I MEAN EVERYTHING STOPS WORKING )

So my questions are:

1. Do I need REDIS server for this and how to do it properly (how to use it properly) ?
2. How to change priority to events when I run `queue:work --queue=high` ? (example for jobs used, but I am not using jobs or listeners)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try to implement `ShouldBroadcastNow` instead of `ShouldBroadcast`. So it doesn't use the queue at all. Broadcasting is finished really fast, no need for a queue.

Comment: I forgot to mention I did when I used sync but it is same with redis.

Comment: @PKeidel and shouldbroadcastnow doesnt use redis event if it is changed it stays with sync

Comment: I'm using `class IncommingMailEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcastNow` with a function `broadcastOn()` and it works with pusher and should work also with socket.io

Comment: It works with sync driver not with redis... Everywhere on web I see that we should use redis instead of sync for better... I opened up 100+ websites for this and still didnt find the answer so I posted all code I have on it.. If I use ShouldBroadcastNow I can remove redis entirely..

Comment: Is your redis server running? And also your socket.io server?

Comment: Redis is/not running I tried with it and without it and it is totally same. And I am not using socketio directly but with laravel echo server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182108/discussion-between-pkeidel-and-learner).